# How to find matrix element with sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql, matrix

I have array and table that I referenced some elements in array. Like  my array

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18 
19 20 21 22 23 24
```

And I have area like Start point **s=9,X=2,Y=2**,Row Count  **R=6**
then I have boxes `9,10,11,15,16,17,21,22,23` 
Now I am trying to write some sql that check if 16 number in this area.I created some logic like `if ((s<16<s+X) || (s+6<16<s+x+6) || (s+12<16<s+x+12) )` but should I write it in one sql query? I am using mySql.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have anything to do with SQL, I don't think, but something like the following condition is probably what you want. Since your example has the same value of X and Y, and "Row Count" sounds more like "number of rows" than "number of items in a row," I may have gotten rows and columns backwards from what you want.

```
set @s=9, @x=2, @y=5, @R=6, @testval=16;

(@testval-1)/@R between (@s-1)/@R and (@s-1)/@R - @y - 1
and (@testval-1)%@R between (@s-1)%@R and (@s-1)%@R - @x - 1
```